# How to plot plot properly?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a dataframe with the next structure:

```
Obj | Err   | Start    | End      | Dur   |   
obj1|  ac   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 1.0   |
obj1|  dc   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 3.0   | 
obj1|  loc  |{datetime}|{datetime}| 4.0   | 
obj2|  ac   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 1.0   | 
obj2|  loc  |{datetime}|{datetime}| 1.0   |
```

I'm trying to build a scatterplot where the x-axis is start time of the AC errors, the y axis = the difference between AC start time and start time of another errors.

What did I try.
I made a dataframe with computed time difference that looks like this:

```
Obj | Err   | Start    | End      | Dur   | Err_y | Start_y  | End_y    | Dur_y | Time diff  
obj1|  ac   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 1.0   | dc    |{datetime}|{datetime}| 3.0   | 2.0
obj1|  ac   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 3.0   | cell  |{datetime}|{datetime}| 1.0   | 0.0  
obj1|  ac   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 4.0   | loc   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 1.0   | 3.0
obj2|  ac   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 1.0   | loc   |{datetime}|{datetime}| 3.0   | 2.0
```

But when I'm trying to plot it I got an error that x and y axes must be of same length.  This is my code for plotting:

```
for obj in data['Obj'].unique():
   AC = data[data['Obj']==obj].reset_index(drop=True)
   plt.figure(figsize=(10,5))
   plt.scatter(AC[AC['Err_x']=='ac']['Start_x'].tolist(),AC[AC['Alarm_y']=='dc']['Time diff'],c='b', label = 'Battery')
   plt.scatter(AC[AC['Err_x']=='ac']['Start_x'].tolist(),AC[AC['Alarm_y']=='loc']['Time diff'],c='b', label = 'Loc')  
   plt.scatter(AC[AC['Err_x']=='ac']['Start_x'].tolist(),AC[AC['Alarm_y']=='cell']['Time diff'],c='b', label = 'Cell')
   plt.ylim(0,200)
   plt.title(obj)
   plt.legend()
```

Maybe there's a way to build such a plot without making additional dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by not an elegant way, so any help is still appreciated.

```
for obj in data['Obj'].unique():    #used the initial dataframe
    DDT=data[data['Obj']=='obj].reset_index(drop=True)    
    DDT['key'] = ((DDT.Obj != DDT.Obj.shift())|(DDT.Err == 'ac')).cumsum()  
    DDDD = pd.merge(DDT.loc[DDT['Err']=='ac'],     #
                 DDT.loc[DDT['err']=='dc'],        #
                 on=['Obj', 'key'],                #
                 how='left')                       # the problem is that this
    DDDD['time_diff'] = (DDDD['Start_y'] -         # part of code needed
    DDDD['Start_x']).dt.total_seconds()//60        # to be duplicated for
    DDDD.dropna(inplace=True)                      # every err that is
    DDDD=DDDD[DDDD['time_diff'] > 0]               # compared with ac
    DDDD=DDDD[DDDD['Dur_x'] >= DDDD['time_diff']]  #
    plt.figure(figsize=(15,7))  
    plt.scatter(DDT[DDT['Err']=='ac']['Start'].tolist(), 
        DDT[DDT['Err']=='ac']['Dur'], c='b', label='AC', s=10)
    plt.scatter(DDDD['Start_x'].tolist(), DDDD['time_diff'], c='g', label = 'DC')  
    plt.legend()
```